# Populating a combo box with a list of functions - Need Advice

Tags: vb.net, combobox, dataset, vb.net-2010

I'm looking for some advice on the best way to handle this.

I have a list of about 200 "Functions" which are listed in a combo box.  When the user selects a 'function' from the list, I need to return the functionID (integer).

I know this can be done easily by binding a dataset to the key and value of the combobox, I'm just not sure about the best way to populate the dataset.

I feel that the way I'm doing it currently is very convoluted:

I currently have a txt file as an embedded resource which I write to a temporary directory, then I use the following code to read in that text file and populate that box by setting the combobox's datasource and Display Member.  It does this by way of a custom class which is implementing System.Collections.IList.

I have pasted the code below.  The reason I want to simplify it is that I dislike writing the text file to the disk, because sometimes it fails.

I'm looking for a way to populate my combobox and return my ID, without writing anything to the user's temp folder.

I am open to changing the format of the embedded resource, and or the code.

The fnlist.txt is formatted currently as follows.

> index, Function Name, ID

The index is only included for sorting (to keep NONE at the bottom, and unknown function at the top), and I suppose is not strictly required.

```
#Region "Function lookup"
Dim path As String = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath
Dim _objFnXtef As New clsFunctionXref(path & "fnList.txt")

Private Sub populate_list()
    functionlist.DataSource = _objFnXtef
    functionlist.DisplayMember = "StrFunction"
End Sub 'Populates the function list

Function get_index(ByVal fnid As Integer)
    Dim iLookupNumber As Integer = fnid

    Dim tmpFnInfo As New clsFunctionInfo
    Dim iReturnIdx As Integer = -1

    If iLookupNumber <> 0 Then
        tmpFnInfo.IFunctionNumber = iLookupNumber
        iReturnIdx = _objFnXtef.IndexOf(tmpFnInfo)
        If iReturnIdx <> -1 Then
            Return iReturnIdx - 1
        Else
            Return get_index(9999)
        End If
    End If
    Return 0
End Function 'Returns index of specified function number
#End Region 'All function list functions
```

Here is the code when a user changes the drop down:

```
Private Sub functionlist_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles functionlist.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim iReturnFuctionID As Integer = 0
    Dim tmpFnInfo As New clsFunctionInfo
    tmpFnInfo = _objFnXtef(functionlist.SelectedIndex)
    iReturnFuctionID = tmpFnInfo.IFunctionNumber
    Func = (iReturnFuctionID)
End Sub
```

And here is the supporting class:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO

Public Class clsFunctionInfo

    Private _idxFunction As Integer

    Public Property IdxFunction() As Integer
        Get
            Return _idxFunction
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _idxFunction = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _strFunction As String

    Public Property StrFunction() As String
        Get
            Return _strFunction
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _strFunction = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _iFunctionNumber As Integer
    Public Property IFunctionNumber() As Integer
        Get
            Return _iFunctionNumber
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _iFunctionNumber = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class


Public Class clsFunctionXref
    Implements System.Collections.IList

    Private _colFunctionInfo As New Collection

    Private _filePath As String
    Public Property FilePath() As String
        Get
            Return _filePath
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _filePath = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal filename As String)
        _filePath = filename

        Dim _idx As Integer = 1
        Dim fields As String()
        Dim delimiter As String = ","
        Dim iFnx As Integer
        Using parser As New TextFieldParser(filename)
            parser.SetDelimiters(delimiter)
            While Not parser.EndOfData
                ' Read in the fields for the current line
                fields = parser.ReadFields()

                Try
                    iFnx = Convert.ToInt16(fields(0).ToString)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("Error reading file.  " & ex.ToString, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                    Exit Sub
                End Try

                Dim objFunction As New clsFunctionInfo
                objFunction.IdxFunction = _idx
                objFunction.IFunctionNumber = iFnx
                objFunction.StrFunction = fields(1).ToString
                Me.Add(objFunction)
                _idx += 1

            End While
        End Using

    End Sub

    Public Function Add(ByVal value As Object) As Integer Implements System.Collections.IList.Add
        If _colFunctionInfo.Contains(value.IFunctionNumber.ToString) Then
            SyncLock Me.SyncRoot
                _colFunctionInfo.Remove(value.IFunctionNumber.ToString)
            End SyncLock
            ReIndex()
        End If
        SyncLock Me.SyncRoot
            _colFunctionInfo.Add(value, value.IFunctionNumber.ToString)
        End SyncLock

    End Function

    Public Sub Clear() Implements System.Collections.IList.Clear
        SyncLock Me.SyncRoot
            _colFunctionInfo.Clear()
        End SyncLock

    End Sub

    Public Function Contains(ByVal value As Object) As Boolean Implements System.Collections.IList.Contains
        If _colFunctionInfo.Contains(value.IFunctionNumber.ToString) Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If

    End Function

    Public ReadOnly Property Count() As Integer Implements System.Collections.ICollection.Count
        Get
            Return _colFunctionInfo.Count
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReadOnly() As Boolean Implements System.Collections.IList.IsReadOnly
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub Remove(ByVal value As Object) Implements System.Collections.IList.Remove
        If _colFunctionInfo.Contains(value.IFunctionNumber.ToString) Then
            SyncLock Me.SyncRoot
                _colFunctionInfo.Remove(value.IFunctionNumber.ToString)
            End SyncLock
            ReIndex()

        End If

    End Sub

    Public Function GetEnumerator() As System.Collections.IEnumerator Implements System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
        Return _colFunctionInfo.GetEnumerator
    End Function


    Public Sub Insert(ByVal index As Integer, ByVal value As Object) Implements System.Collections.IList.Insert

        SyncLock Me.SyncRoot
            If _colFunctionInfo.Contains(value.IFunctionNumber.ToString) Then
                _colFunctionInfo.Remove(value.IFunctionNumber.ToString)
            End If
            If index < _colFunctionInfo.Count Then
                _colFunctionInfo.Add(value, value.IFunctionNumber.ToString, index - 1)

            Else
                _colFunctionInfo.Add(value, value.IFunctionNumber.ToString)
            End If
        End SyncLock
        ReIndex()

    End Sub

    Public Sub RemoveAt(ByVal index As Integer) Implements System.Collections.IList.RemoveAt
        SyncLock Me.SyncRoot
            If _colFunctionInfo.Count <= index And index > 0 Then
                _colFunctionInfo.Remove(index)

            End If
        End SyncLock
        ReIndex()
    End Sub


    Private Sub ReIndex()
        SyncLock Me.SyncRoot


            Dim iReIndex As Integer = 1
            Dim colTemp As New Collection
            For Each obj As clsFunctionInfo In _colFunctionInfo
                obj.IdxFunction = iReIndex
                colTemp.Add(obj, obj.IFunctionNumber)
                iReIndex += 1

            Next
            _colFunctionInfo.Clear()
            For Each obj1 As clsFunctionInfo In colTemp
                _colFunctionInfo.Add(obj1, obj1.IFunctionNumber.ToString)
            Next
            colTemp.Clear()
        End SyncLock

    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property IsSynchronized() As Boolean Implements System.Collections.ICollection.IsSynchronized
        Get
            Return True
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property SyncRoot() As Object Implements System.Collections.ICollection.SyncRoot
        Get
            Dim _syncRoot As New Object
            Return _syncRoot
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property IsFixedSize() As Boolean Implements System.Collections.IList.IsFixedSize
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub CopyTo(ByVal array As System.Array, ByVal index As Integer) Implements System.Collections.ICollection.CopyTo
        For Each obj As clsFunctionInfo In _colFunctionInfo
            array(index) = obj
            index += 1
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Function IndexOf(ByVal value As Object) As Integer Implements System.Collections.IList.IndexOf
        SyncLock Me.SyncRoot
            Dim tmpFnInfo As New clsFunctionInfo
            Dim tmpFunctionNumber As Integer
            Dim tmpidx As Integer = -1

            tmpFnInfo = DirectCast(value, clsFunctionInfo)
            tmpFunctionNumber = tmpFnInfo.IFunctionNumber

            For Each obj In _colFunctionInfo
                tmpFnInfo = DirectCast(obj, clsFunctionInfo)
                If tmpFunctionNumber = tmpFnInfo.IFunctionNumber Then
                    tmpidx = tmpFnInfo.IdxFunction
                    Exit For

                End If
            Next
            Return tmpidx
        End SyncLock
    End Function

    Default Public Property Item(ByVal index As Integer) As Object Implements System.Collections.IList.Item
        Get
            index += 1
            Return _colFunctionInfo(index)

        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Object)

        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

I'm sorry that this is so long, but I know that someone on here has some great suggestions on how to handle this because I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around it.  I think I've been starring at it too long.

Comment: Did you ever try to 'just' load all txt file lines to the combobox ?

Comment: I certainly like tinstaafl's suggestion of reading from the stream.  I'm wondering however if anyone has any thoughts on using a datatable/dataset to store the info, that way I don't have to keep reading from the stream each time, i can just fill the dataset/table when the application loads and then query it from there.

Comment: work with datatable / dataset is will easier and safe coz we dont have to worry about access rights, space control and others .. the system will do it for you ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you have the text file as an embedded resource, you can open a stream to the file from there, without having to write it to disk.  The ResourceReader class should help you.

Comment: So use the same code, but instead of writing the actual file and reading the written file, I would just read directly from the stream and bypass writing to a temp folder?  I suppose that would save me from re-doing the part of the code that works.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I did it 4 years ago, but just noticed I never marked the question as answered!